# Git merge: why do I get a lot of merge conflicts after modifying the source on both linux and windows?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I was doing some work at home over the weekend and used git to merge code changes back to my office computer (connected via a vpn) and found some very ugly merge problems.

First of all the merge should have been very clean as everything was committed at the office on Friday and I only made changes to my home computer on Saturday and Sunday. But when I pulled the changes to my office computer I ended up with a ton of merge conflicts.

I cleaned up the merge conflicts, but then I found that many of the files (from what I can tell any file that I changed over the weekend) had `<<<<<<< HEAD" and ">>>>>>> D1/master` throughout the files. For example:

```
diff --git a/web/Web.Controller/Helpers/FormsAuthentication.cs b/web/Web.Controller/Helpers/FormsAuthentication.cs
index 8571f53..4a9c9fc 100644
-- a/web/Web.Controller/Helpers/FormsAuthentication.cs
++ b/web/Web.Controller/Helpers/FormsAuthentication.cs
@@ -10,7 +10,10 @@
    /// </summary>
    public class FormsAuthenticationUtility : IAuthenticationUtility
    {
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======
>>>>>>> D1/master
        #region IAuthentication Members

        /// <summary>
```

I was able to fix the code using `kdiff` by comparing with the source code copied from my home computer, but this just seems completely messed up.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Can you show the graph of the branch that you merged from and the branch that you merged to, e.g. `git log --graph master home/master` or at least exactly what the relationship between the two branches that you merged?

Comment: First I cloned the repo from my office computer to my home computer, made changes on the home computer (including a branch), committed and merged everything on the home repo to it's master branch. Then I pulled the changes from the home repo to the office repo and tried to merge into the office master branch.

Comment: did you check whether your home computer has the same core.autocrlf  setting as at the office? if not, please have a look at the link in my answer which helped me in a (probably) similar case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when Windows files where merged into my Linux repo, so that was a CRLF issue. I could finally fix that with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273). IIRC this had to be done *before* merging, but it's been a while and honestly I forgot to write it down...

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ran the commands on my office repo and didn't find any files to fix.  But when I ran it on my home repo it did find several files where it replaced the crlf.  I will keep it in mind before I merge the next time.

Comment: @Dan also remember to check for a consistent autocrlf setting

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem like this come up when going from Windows to *Nix and back due to their different treatment of newline characters. Git might be picking up on those differences and for whatever reason failing to merge.

Maybe try `--ignore-space-at-eol`?

**Edit:**

White space actually *does* matter when merging. It might not matter in your exact case, but there are contexts where it might make a difference. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences) seems to address what should be done to resolve the conflicts much better than I ever could.

Comment: There might be something to this as several of the merge conflicts were due to unix newline formatting, although I'm only using windows computers.

Comment: The --ignore-space-at-eol option is only for git diff, how does this help me when merging?

Comment: Probably incorrectly, I thought that git merge automatically used git diff for some of the work. See edit for a more thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  To illuminate further, this is not a new repo and I've done several merges between these two computers and never had a problem.  Like I said this should have been a very clean merge as there were no changes made on the office computer and only changes on my home computer over the weekend.  But on Monday it got ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the CRLF problem while merging: it sparked off a recent discussion [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/149802). You might might also want to try to build a reduced case with a few files to find out what exactly is causing this problem.