# Fix git line feeds in heavily branched repo?

Tags: git

Our git repo has been running happily for years with CRLF in all the files and has a large number of active feature branches.

Now I know how to replace all the CRLF's within one branch in just a single commit. But no matter how I try to do this, I always get full block-level conflicts when I try to merge the upstream branch into downstream, even if I do the "same" replacement on the downstream branch first.

How can I do this without creating a total mess ?

Comment: This question may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences