# Why does git show a conflict between two apparently identical added files?

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-cherry-pick

I have a project that was started in TFS, then moved to Git.  Unfortunately, the guy who moved it to Git just checked in the current files instead of using git-tfs.  I'm trying to rebase his new commits in Git on top of the commits I pulled from TFS using git-tfs.

To do this, I'm simply rebasing his commits on top of the git-tfs commits.  (I realize this will mess up remote Git branches, but we're a small team and it'll be OK.  I've also tried cherry-picking instead but I hit the same problem.)

The problem I'm running into is a set of conflicts that look like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
namespace OurNiftyProject
{
    public enum CardType
    { 
        Visa = 0,
        MasterCard = 1
    }
}
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
namespace OurNiftyProject
{
    public enum CardType
    { 
        Visa = 0,
        MasterCard = 1
    }
}
>>>>>>> Add a bunch of stuff.
```

It appears that this is a conflict between a commit from the TFS side that added these files, and a commit on the Git side that added them (as the Git repo started out empty).

The logical thing would be to skip this commit, perhaps, but there are a few files in it (say ten out of a couple hundred) that are new.  Those don't cause conflicts, of course.

Why can't Git figure out on its own that the two files are identical?  Even if I use `--ignore-whitespace` when I rebase, Git still shows dozens of files like this that appear to be identical.  I'm at a loss for how to resolve this.

Comment: Does `diff` give you a difference as well?

Comment: Could it be line-ending differences?

Comment: "Even if I use `--ignore-whitespace` when I rebase..."

Answer (score 11):

It should be about line-ending differences, as [ebneter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150032/ebneter) comments.
I have already detailed a long time ago how git merge wasn't good at ignoring those differences (as opposed to whitespaces differences):
"[Is it possible for git-merge to ignore line-ending differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences)"

That is why a *consistent* eol conversion policy is necessary for those repository on heterogeneous environment.
See "[Distributing git configuration with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)".

Comment: Does Git really consider line-ending differences distinct from whitespace differences!?  I thought line endings *were* whitespace!

Comment: @Kyralessa: not exactly. http://gitster.livejournal.com/28862.html mentions `cr-at-eol`: with `trailing-space`, does not trigger if the character before such a carriage-return is not a whitespace, but it is *not activated by default*.

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing a similar thing and just found out "-X ignore-space-at-eol". It is available for both merge and rebase. Seems to be doing the right thing but makes it death slow for me.

Comment: Maybe they found a speedup, because for me adding the flag doesn't slow me down.  git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0

Answer (score 2):

I just bumped into this issue, followed by this post just to realize it's a line-ending scenario for me as well.

So FWIW, this happened in my case because I used to have "Use Windows style line endings", but at some point, for a different project, I reconfigured it to "Use Unix style line endings" (these configurations are available from the Git Setup program).

Returning to "Use Windows style line endings" solved the problem without using "--ignore-whitespace"

Answer (score 2):

If you can rule out invisible changes due to different line endings, you may want to check if the files have **different modes (e.g. if the executable bit is set)**. Git shows the full file in a diff when the file mode changed.