# Different states with GIT DIFF

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a file which has conflicts.

```
REGION lifetime counter
    (*
    //for test purposes lifetimecounter goes to movement detection in set delayed outputs
    IF #O AND NOT #fp_lifetime
        AND #CCF.config.se_operating_counter_enable.value
        AND #CCF.status.s_active
    THEN
        #CCF.status.av_lifetime.value += 2;
    END_IF;
    #fp_lifetime := #O;
    *)
<<<<<<< HEAD
    "S-B"
=======
    "S-A"
>>>>>>> base/master
END_REGION
```

Delete: `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `"S-B"`, `=======` and `>>>>>>> base/master`

After editing this file in NOTEPAD, resolving the conflict, I execute the command:
`git diff <path\to\the\file>`
In most cases I get the right result:

```
$  git diff <path\to\the\file>
diff --cc <path\to\the\file>
index 286d51c,b189c82..0000000
--- a/<path\to\the\file>
+++ b/<path\to\the\file>
```

However, sometimes I also receive the following, and here the reason is unknown:

```
$  git diff <path\to\the\file>
diff --cc <path\to\the\file>
index 286d51c,b189c82..0000000
--- a/<path\to\the\file>
+++ b/<path\to\the\file>
@@@ -485,7 -485,7 +485,6 @@@ BEGI
            END_IF;
            #fp_lifetime := #O;
            *)
-           "S-B"
-       END_REGION
+           "S-A"
 -      END_REGION
```

Where do the different outputs come from if I always execute the same thing in the file?

Final state:

```
REGION lifetime counter
    (*
    //for test purposes lifetimecounter goes to movement detection in set delayed outputs
    IF #O AND NOT #fp_lifetime
        AND #CCF.config.se_operating_counter_enable.value
        AND #CCF.status.s_active
    THEN
        #CCF.status.av_lifetime.value += 2;
    END_IF;
    #fp_lifetime := #O;
    *)
    "S-A"
END_REGION
```

Comment: @Brian61354270 that happens in cases when you have changes coming from different branches (depending on the indentation of `+`/`-`, you know how the current file looks when compared with each _parent_).

Comment: can you post what it looks like in the _final_ state? At least the block between `REGION` and `END_REGION` (both lines included). Actually the same block from  `HEAD` would also be welcome.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Doesn't it depend where you are when you say `git diff`? Maybe you should add `HEAD` to your `git diff` command.

Comment: If I read it correctly, `END_REGION` is probably not in the original position or there is a different character following it (even an EOL or EOF) from what it was on each branch. Now, about the _other_ lines, it looks correct. From `HEAD`, it looks like you deleted `S-B` and added `S-A`. From the other parent, it only marks the line about `END_REGION` as having changed.

Comment: @eftshift0: If I really change something in the line with `END_REGION`, e.g. insert a space, the output looks different.
`-      END_REGION`
`++       END_REGION`

Comment: This is a _looooooong shot_ **but** still possible..... I think you changed _that_ line (`END_REGION`) on both branches **with the same change(!!!!!)** when compared with their common ancestor. Is that the case?

Comment: _and_, if that is the case, I **think** this behavior is coming from a rather recent change to make the size of conflicts smaller by accepting lines that where changed the same way in the different parent branches when there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do the different outputs come from if I always execute the same thing in the file?

When git marks a file as conflicted you can inspect which versions that git has used as inputs with `git ls-files -u`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466484/23118) for more details.

With that information you can create some temporary tags like

```bash
git tag inspect-1 ad5e6cfb620eb3086a399bd8dd63f039fa120358
git tag inspect-2 73dab4ca75450b2aeb048a5e5632011d95064e58
git tag inspect-3 12c32798081dd59a51295275ce1119f5d1662422
```

And then launch `gitk "--exclude=refs/notes/*" --all &` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to search for each tag. You then will be able to see where each contributing version is comming from.

---

The exclude notes ting is to ignore the cached test results from [git-test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test), because you always use it to test and verify all your commits on a branch, right? Right? If not you really, really, really, really should!