# How to make a Git merge operation ignore identical changes made to both branches?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Lets assume that we have one development branch 'A', and two sub branches 'B1' and 'B2', (both taken from A). Lets say that you run a *format code command* (in our case ReSharper's cleanup code) on the entire project in B1 and B2.

Now, when we try to merge B2 into B1, Git will report conflicts on *all files* in the project (quite a large number in our case). When looking closer at each conflict, it seems like Git thinks theres a conflict even though the exact same change was made in both B1 and B2(?)

Is there a way, custom driver/git attribute etc that will make a Git merge operation not report a conflict if the files in B1 and B2 are exactly the same?

Maybe I've got it wrong, maybe it is a whitespace/line ending issue (eg different line endings in B1 and B2) in which case I can find the solution here on stack overflow.

Comment: you can inspect conflicts by opening the files in an editor, you'll be able to see why git sees conflicts

Comment: How much work other than the refactoring was performed in these branches?  I can't speak for Git specifically, but generally, you'd do this only in one branch, merge the changes to the parent, then have the second branch pick up that refactor.

Comment: Did you try to use kdiff3 as mergetool in git? It usually can handle those trivial conflicts on its own.

Comment: @OrionRogue: Both B1 and B2 have a pure 'refactor code commit', ie no other work was made in this commit. Of course there are other commits ion each branch which might lead to 'real' conflicts. I guess I could eg cherrypick the 'refactoring commit' from B1 and put it into B2 but then the files which are exclusively in B2 wont be refactored.

Comment: @EmilB, I have a sneaking suspicion that you're going to have to weigh the cost/benefit of having one branch win, then refreshing, or manually merging all those files as one large merge activity.  If the actual changes between the two branches isn't ACTUALLY a lot, you might be better off with the first option.

Comment: It seems like a lot of the reported comments is however due to inconsistent line endings. Thanks for all the great input.

Comment: This question explains, how to merge ignoring white spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I had similar issue after a lot of cherry-pick from (and to) a side branch where I after merged with my main branch. A lot of conflicts with identical change. I solved this with a merge strategy:

```
git checkout main-branch
merge --no-commit -s recursive -X ours side-branch
```

you can change "ours" to "theirs". Be careful because all conflicts are automatically solved choosing "ours" or "theirs" side. In my case I had few mis-merges due to this, and I fixed manually. See others interesting options of merge strategies here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

You can also try to use a rebase (in my case it did not work well because the branchs were too different and I had a new conflict in each new rebase interaction). See this: http://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/git-merge-after-git-cherry-pick-avoiding-duplicate-commits/

Comment: He only wants this when the changes are IDENTICAL.  This will always take your changes.

Comment: I know and I said that in the answer.