# Resolve merge conflicts: Force overwrite all files

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I am working on a git repository *by myself* (so yes, I know the implications and the warnings of doing this) and somehow one of the trees got a commit after being pushed when it shouldn't have.

Now I'm trying to pull back and it's complaining about hundreds of merge conflicts.

Is there a way to tell git to *forcefully* overwrite any and all files locally that are coming from the remote server? Is there a faster way than doing `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and then doing the pull?

On that same note, is there a way to do the same with with a simple merge? Everything I've seen suggests to check out each and every file during the merge conflict resolution stage, but with hundreds of files it's just not possible to do so manually.

Comment: why don't you just blow away your sandbox and git clone it again?

Comment: I was hoping for something that didn't take as much time. The project is large and would take a good amount of time to clone.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are three simple solutions to copy the last version that is in you remote repository, discarding all changes that you have made locally:

1. Discard your repository and clone again. This is the most simple solution, but if your repository is big, it can take a long time, and may require extra effort like re`configure`ing, etc.
2. Discard the local changes with `git reset --hard <hash>` and then do a `git pull`. The problem is you need to first find a commit that precedes whatever change history you are trying to avoid.  After resetting to that commit hash, do a `git pull`.
3. Do a `git fetch` to bring the updates to your local reference of the remote branch (usually origin/master) and then do a `git reset --hard` passing this reference, ie, `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: #3 was pretty smart. Good answer. Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way. Just a note: use back-quotes (`) to denote code or command line stuff.

Comment: `git checkout --theirs .` seems to work if the merge does not include any deletions

Comment: Years later and I've determined #3 to be _the definitive_ correct answer. Learning how `fetch` and refs work is very important to using Git effectively.

Comment: After running the `git fetch origin my_branch`, then trying `git reset --hard origin/my_branch` I get the following error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/my_branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`  Is the issue with the "`working tree`" bit?

Answer (score 11):

```
git reset --hard {remote_repository_name}/{branch_name}
```

Example:

```
git reset --hard upstream/branch1
```

If you are working with a branch you can use the above code.But before that, you have to set (upstream or origin) to your local repository,

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/lakini/example.git
```

here,https://github.com/lakini/example.git is the remote upstream repository.

Same as like this we can work in the remote repository(origin) as well.

```
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```