# git rebase does not complete successfully with ''both modified' message

Tags: git

I am trying to copy a list of commits from the dev_branch to my current branch, using `git rebase current_branch dev_branch`.

I see `git rebase` does not complete successfully, and says:

```
both modified: file1.c
both modified: file2.c
```

When I open these files in an editor, I don't see any merge conflict. Can git automatically merge these for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Differences in line endings?

Comment: I think your command is wrong. The correct syntax is `git rebase <the name base> <your branch>`. So if you are in current_branch and want to get the changes from dev_branch, you should write `git rebase dev_branch` or `git rebase dev_branch current_branch`.

Comment: as @EricWoodruff mentioned, it seems a line ending issue. If that is the case, you can check the answer of similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences

Comment: @lemiorhan , I am just following this example http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/using-git-cherry-pick-to-simulate-git-rebase.html. It is using 'git rebase foo bar' where foo is the current_branch, bar is the dev_branch

Comment: @michael I checked the link you mentioned. bar is your current branch, not foo. Rebase means changing the base of your current branch (bar) on top of another (that is foo in this case).