# How to ignore merge conflicts for identical changes

Tags: git, merge

I got this merge conflict:

```
my %frame_name =  (
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
    G => 'GOTO',
    D => 'DBGF',
    C => 'FROM',
=======
    G => 'GOTO',
    D => 'DBGF',
    C => 'FROM',
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
);
```

It it possible to force git for merging such conflicts automatically?

Comment: Is it a whitespace difference (tabs versus spaces, MSWin versus *nix newlines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abort your merge and try your merge while ignoring white-space:

```
git merge --abort
git merge -Xignore-space-change whitespace
```

> The first option ignores whitespace completely when comparing lines,
>   the second treats sequences of one or more whitespace characters as
>   equivalent.

[More information](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging) (see the "Ignoring Whitespace" section)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences) as well.